# I want to use the ”For each” function in this powershell script to remove user profile from SharePoint 2016. Use of "For each function"

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-3.0

I have created a powershell script to remove user profile from SharePoint 2016. However, I need the script to collect data from .CSV where all the user Samaccount name and principal are stored. If the user exists then to remove the user profile. below is my script. I want to use the ”For each” function in this script. Could any expert help please?

```
#Import
$DEACTIVATED_AD_USERS_CSV = "D:\Te……Deactivated_Users_WDRmg_208.csv"
$SiteURL = “ (https:...)..”
$deactUsers = Import-Csv $DEACTIVATED_AD_USERS_CSV -Delimiter "`t"
$AccountName= "…"
#Get Objects
$ServiceContext  = Get-SPServiceContext -site $SiteURL
$UserProfileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)
#Get the User Profile
$UserProfile = $UserProfileManager.GetUserProfile($AccountName)
#remove user profile
$UserProfileManager.RemoveUserProfile($AccountName);
```

Comment: What is the name of the column in the CSV that contains the account name?

Comment: samaccountname . Sorry forgot to mention this

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value from the `samaccountname` column of each row to the `$AccountName` variable:

```
#Import
$DEACTIVATED_AD_USERS_CSV = "D:\Te……Deactivated_Users_WDRmg_208.csv"
$SiteURL = "https://team.wdrmg.de/..."
$deactUsers = Import-Csv $DEACTIVATED_AD_USERS_CSV -Delimiter "`t"

foreach($user in $deactUsers){
    # Grab the account name from the csv
    $AccountName= $user.samaccountname

    #Get Objects
    $ServiceContext  = Get-SPServiceContext -site $SiteURL
    $UserProfileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)
    #Get the User Profile
    $UserProfile = $UserProfileManager.GetUserProfile($AccountName)
    #remove user profile
    $UserProfileManager.RemoveUserProfile($AccountName)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it says -"A user with corresponding Guid could not be found in the database."
At line:18 char:5 - line 18 is the last line . Could you please clarify what do you mean by "Assign the value from the samaccountname column of each row to the $AccountName variable:" ? thanks a lot

Comment: `$AccountName = $user.samaccountname` <- this is the assignment I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes, I did , This is how it looks like-   
foreach($user in $deactUsers){
    # Grab the account name from the csv
    $AccountName= $user.SamAccountName

Comment: my csv data column looks like this - 
Samaccountname  - Userprincipalname - Name 
xxx                             xxx                               xxx